# C# merge multiple lists by id and summing the property

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I got a grapic class which looks like this:

```
public class Graphic
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

and now i have 3 lists of grapic:

```
public void myFunction()
{
    List<Graphic> l1= new List<Graphic> ();
    List<Graphic> l2= new List<Graphic> ();
    List<Graphic> l3= new List<Graphic> ();

    l1.Add(new Graphic {id = 1, Counter = 4});
    l1.Add(new Graphic {id = 2, Counter = 2});
    l1.Add(new Graphic {id = 3, Counter = 9});
    l1.Add(new Graphic {id = 4, Counter = 1});

    l2.Add(new Graphic {id = 1, Counter = 1});
    l2.Add(new Graphic {id = 2, Counter = 2});
    l2.Add(new Graphic {id = 3, Counter = 3});
    l2.Add(new Graphic {id = 5, Counter = 1});

    l3.Add(new Graphic {id = 1, Counter = 12});
    l3.Add(new Graphic {id = 7, Counter = 1});
    l3.Add(new Graphic {id = 8, Counter = 3});
    l3.Add(new Graphic {id = 4, Counter = 1});
}
```

And i need a code which will merge these 3 lists, each graphic with it's ID and the counter property will be summed up, so the result will be:

```
var mergedList = {
    Graphic {id = 1, Counter = 17},
    Graphic {id = 2, Counter = 4},
    Graphic {id = 3, Counter = 12},
    Graphic {id = 4, Counter = 2},
    Graphic {id = 5, Counter = 1},
    Graphic {id = 7, Counter = 1},
    Graphic {id = 8, Counter = 3}
}
```

any idea will help me.
Is there a way to do that efficiently with LINQ?

Comment: Yap. Had a look at groupby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.Concat` to merge the 3 lists and then `GroupBy` to get all the `Counter` values of the different `id`s:

```
var result = l1.Concat(l2)
               .Concat(l3)
               .GroupBy(item => new { item.id, item.Geometry }, item => item.Counter)
               .Select(group => new Graphic
               {
                   id = group.Key,
                   Counter = group.Sum()
               }).ToList();
```

See collection initializer for a neater way to initialize the lists:

```
List<Graphic> l1 = new List<Graphic>
{
    new Graphic { id = 2, Counter = 2 },
    new Graphic { id = 3, Counter = 9 },
    new Graphic { id = 4, Counter = 1 },
    new Graphic { id = 1, Counter = 4 },
};
```

I also suggest reading C# [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) for the naming of your function and the properties.

Comment: Thanks! that worked for this example. but, if i had another property for Graphic, named 'geometry' , that i want to include in the merged graphic, but not summing it up, just copy him to the merged graphic. can I do that inside LINQ?

Comment: @RonAvraham - Yes but you need to see what is the behavior you want for it? Do you have a unique value for each id? If so add it to the group by, if not then you need to define what behavior you want (for example concatenations, first, last....)

Comment: each id has the same 'geometry' on all 3 lists. i just want to take one of them to the merged grapic.

Comment: @RonAvraham - then add it as part of the GroupBy's key. See update

Comment: @RonAvraham - you are welcome. Try next time to see the different documentations and SO linq documentation ;)